# Startup Issue on HP ENVY x360 Convertible 15 ed1xxx - No Display

Tags: bios, black-screen-of-death, start-screen

I'm encountering a problem with my HP ENVY x360 Convertible 15 laptop (model ed1xxx). Upon attempting to power it on, there is no display visible, and even the HP logo doesn't appear. I've done some research and it seems that this might be connected to a BIOS issue. However, I'm not familiar with the steps to resolve this matter.

If anyone has experienced a similar situation or has recommendations on how to address this problem, I would greatly appreciate your assistance. I'm open to following detailed instructions if provided.

Comment: Try an external monitor and if that works, most likely you have a hardware issue that needs service. You need your display to get into BIOS, so probably take it to a local service shop and see what they can do.